# Несколько версий python

Tags: python, python-3.6

У меня несколько версий Python(2.7 | 3.6 | 3.7). Если удалю не ту, то система ведь может сломаться? Но обращаться через python3.7 не очень удобно, могу ли я как то это изменить? Может я могу просто что либо прописать, что бы при обращении через (python) код срабатывал через python3.7? Такой же что-бы библиотеки устанавливались на python3.7?

ОС: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Это вопрос для "Клуба телепатов"? Что за система?

Comment: @gregzakharov Прошу прощение, забыл добавить. Исправил!

Comment: А шебанг вам на что? Пишите в самом начале скрипта, например, `#!/usr/bin/env python3.7` - вот вам и решение проблемы.

Comment: shebang, alias - чем плохи эти вещи?

Comment: Удаление системного Python (версий, который были установлены в системе изначально) под Linux приведет к непредсказуемым последствиям. Проверено опытом сотен (тысяч) граблеходящих пользователей.

Comment: `alias py=python<whatever-you-want>` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Для питона есть чудестная штука называется venv. Ставится через apt или pip и запускается через комманду virtualenv. Далее просто прописываешь окружение в коробке и запускаешь программу изолированно от других версий python.